# Does splitting Model.all into different starting letters slow load time down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Let's say I have a generic model, just called "Model", with a few thousand instances. Right now I'm displaying Model.all on a page, like this:

```
<% Model.all.order(:name).each do |model| %>
  <%= model.name %>
<% end %>
```

but I'm considering splitting it up by first letter, something like this:

```
A
<% Model.where(name.chars.first: "A").order(:name).each do |model| %>
  <%= model.name %>
<% end %>
B
<% Model.where(name.chars.first: "B").order(:name).each do |model| %>
  <%= model.name %>
<% end %>
C
<% Model.where(name.chars.first: "C").order(:name).each do |model| %>
  <%= model.name %>
<% end %>
...
```

and so on. Would this method take significantly longer to load than just the straightforward `Model.all`?

Comment: Latter will throw queries multiple times. It will be slow if you query for all the alphabets.

Comment: You can perform caching too. It will take first time load but after execution goes faster than earlier. If you want to stick on your same approach. set caching expire time to 1 day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through `things` collection and insert a starting letter when needed:

```
things = Thing.order(:name)

current_letter = 'A'
things.each do |thing|
  if thing.name.chars.first != current_letter  
    current_letter = thing.name.chars.first    
    puts current_letter    
  end  
  puts thing.name # just as an example  
end
```

Comment: Do you think this method would also take significantly longer than Model.all?

Comment: No, it's just one query, so it will take exactly the same time as `Model.all`

Comment: By the way, would it make any difference in speed to load an attribute (table column) as opposed to an instance method (defined in the Model.rb)?

Comment: It depends how many records there are but in general you want to avoid to store record instances in the memory so loading an attribute may be a better solution.